# Incremental upgrade of EOL version of Ubuntu Gnome via DVD

Tags: dvd, live-cd, ubuntu-gnome, do-release-upgrade, livedvd

Moderators please read carefully, and think before calling a duplication, this is not the same as existing questions. The background is, but not but the question.

**Background:**
As I understand it, with Ubuntu Gnome if you want to upgrade the distribution you can do so by upgrading to the next incremental update. So for example on my computer I could not hop from 15.04 to 16.04 LTS directly, I'd have to go from 15.04 to 15.10, and then from 15.10 to 16.04 LTS.

I'd like to do that only at this time (July 27th 2017) both 15.04 and 15.10 are at EOL and so not supported. Apparently it can be done by changing etc/apt/sources.list to point to an old archive, but I've not got this to work. I typically get the following error whether or not I am pointing to the new or old sources. The following scenario is what I get before and after changes the sources.list.

```
sudo apt-get update
...
sudo do-release-upgrade
...
An upgrade from 'vivid' to 'xenial' is not supported with this tool.
```

For what it's worth I spent several hours trying to do this on my work machine and threw in the towel and upgraded using the 17.04 DVD loosing most, if not all of my programs and configurations. Now I turn my attention to my home machine which also has 15.04 on it.

**Question 1:**
So that's the back story now for what I am asking. I have the install DVDs for both 15.10 and 16.04. Now I know when you boot from a CD you get the option to upgrade your version and it will 'try' to keep your programs.

Is this different, than say doing  a 'sudo do-release-upgrade' incremental upgrade? I ask this because on my office PC I was able to use a 17.04 dvd to upgrade from 15.04 but I might as well have done a clean install for what it wiped out. I've done incremental upgrades before using 'do-release-upgrade' and its generally not required my apps to be re-installed and configured.

**Question 2:**
If the answer to question one is 'yes there is a difference', is there a convenient way to do perform an incremental backup using a DVD. Lets say I had an old friend out in the sticks with a internet speed barely good enough for email. Could I then do for him a release-upgrade using the install DVD with few to no side effects as I have experienced when doing it via the command line?

**Finally:**
I suppose overall what I am asking is how does 'do-release-upgrade' differ from a CD based upgrade when doing an incremental upgrade of an Ubuntu distribution?. If someone can hit this last question here on the head, you have nailed it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `sudo do-release-upgrade' focuses on updating everything and removing broken packages, this method updates trying to keep as many programs as possible. Note: in some cases, it is impossible to keep old packages: For example, 'libav' being replaced with 'ffmpeg'. the only fix is to hope the broken package has a replacement that uses the new library.

First run: `apt-mark showhold` to be sure nothing is being held back.
If you find held packages then remove the hold and update them I find `aptitude` is the easiest way for marking and updating multiple packages at one time. `Aptitude` will also suggest removal of orphaned packages (packages that are no longer used by anything).
`sudo apt-get autoremove` will also remove packages that are no longer used.

After your system is fully up to date in the current version, change you sources to point to the version of Ubuntu that you want.
EX: change "trusty" to 'xenial"

Next run this series of commands:

`sudo apt-get update` This updates the package list
`sudo apt-get upgrade` This upgrades packages that can be upgraded without changing other packages. thus easing the dependency resolving in the next step.
`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` This upgrades the remaining packages that can be upgraded with a minimal amount of removals.

You now have the new version of Ubuntu, and need to clean up obsoleted packages. Again I find `aptitude` to be the easiest way to do this.
Open `aptitude` and it will already have a list of suggested removals (orphaned packages), it is generally safe to remove them.
Now go through the remaining obsolete packages. In most cases, remaining packages have been replaced with another: ie gt4 with gt5 and gstreamer0.1-good with gstreamer1.0-good. The replacements will be under the heading of new packages.
This step is the most critical and why I like `aptitude`, replacing the obsoleted packages will often break other packages; however, the broken package usually also has a replacement package to correct dependencies.
`Aptitude` will list broken packages and recommend fixes. Check over actions to be performed before committing to them.

When you have finish, clean your package cache: `sudo apt-get autoclean` this will remove the package cache for packages that are no longer used.

Comment: Why are you mentioning xbuntu? I've not even asked for that, but I suppose the process id the same. I did all this yesterday on my work computer and got the Error mentioned in by background info (because the version has reached end of life).   Can I not just upgrade using a CD to the same effect?

Comment: sorry edited Xubuntu to Ubuntu, they are the same except for the desktop. I believe upgrading via CD may have the same effect as do-release-upgrade, and the CD image may not be fully up to date.also you would have to download the DVD set to get all packages unless you are going to uses internet while updating. 15.04 to 15.10 would be vivid to wily.

Comment: Well it did fix my problem, although it did not directly address my question. Many thanks. BTW if anyone wants to answer the question about CD Rom upgrade vs do-release-upgrade there are still points up for grabs.